# How does React.Suspense know that a promise has resolved?

Tags: reactjs

With React 18 we can use `Suspense` to conditionally render a component once a promise has been fulfilled.

Here is a basic example (in Typescript):

```
function SomeComponent({dataId}) {
  const supplier = createSupplier(dataId)
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <Something supplier={supplier}"/>
    </Suspense>)
}

function Something({supplier}: { supplier: () => Data }) {
    const data = supplier()
    return <span>Loaded: {data.title}</span>
}
```

This is how `createSupplier` is defined:

```
function wrapPromise<T>(promise: Promise<T>): () => T {
    let status = 'pending'
    let response: T
    const suspender = promise.then(
        (res) => {
            status = 'success'
            response = res
        },
        (err) => {
            status = 'error'
            response = err
        },
    )
    return () => {
        switch (status) {
            case 'pending':
                throw suspender
            case 'error':
                throw response
            default:
                return response
        }
    }
}

function createSupplier(dataId: number) : () => Data {
    const data: Promise<Data> = fetchData(dataId) // External API
    return wrapPromise<Data>(data)
}
```

**This example works as expected**. We see the loading message and then the component fully renders once the data has been fetched. However, I don't understand why it works.

How can `Suspense` know that the promise has resolved? I'm worrying about possible performance implications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React's `Suspense` is used mainly for managing your lazy loaded components and providing a better user experience.

By "splitting" your bundle into smaller chunks of code (lazy load), you improve initial load time since you would only be loading the critical/necessary code the page/app needs to properly function and then, load the rest of the code as needed.

Now, I think you are basically asking how `Suspense` works under the hood.

Code-splitting is a feature supported by bundlers like Webpack, Rollup, Browserify, etc. which can create multiple bundles that can be dynamically loaded at runtime.

Now consider this example:

```
import("./math").then(math => {
  console.log(math.add(16, 26));
});
```

When your bundler comes across this syntax, it automatically starts code-splitting your app since you are dynamically loading a piece of code. Now let's take the example specifically to React, by lazy loading a component.

```
const Component = React.lazy(() => import('./Component'));
```

This is doing basically the same as the import above, but at a component level. `React.lazy` takes a function that calls a dynamic import. This will return a `promise` that will resolve to a module with the default export containing this component.

What `Suspense` does under the hood is "watch" for 3 states of this promise: pending, fullfilled or rejected.

When the promise is **pending**, you'll see your `fallback` or loader.

When the promise is **fullfilled** you will then see your component rendered.

If the promise is **rejected** then you will of course encounter an error which you should handle with an `ErrorBoundary`.

All of this also applies when using `Suspense` for other cases, like data fetching and the example you are providing.

Hope this helps you.